having issues with latest ubuntu 24.04.01lts and intel oneapi base gnome ver.46 intel graphics-(adl gt2) linux 6.8.0-41- 12gen i-5 1235u
After this operation, 1,837 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 193500 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../0-libglvnd0_1.7.0-2101~22.04_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libglvnd0:i386 (1.7.0-2101~22.04) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-WFP5wd/0-libglvnd0_1.7.0-21
01~22.04_i386.deb (--unpack):
trying to overwrite shared '/usr/share/doc/libglvnd0/changelog.Debian.gz', whic
h is different from other instances of package libglvnd0:i386
Preparing to unpack .../1-libegl1_1.7.0-2101~22.04_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libegl1:i386 (1.7.0-2101~22.04) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-WFP5wd/1-libegl1_1.7.0-2101
~22.04_i386.deb (--unpack):
trying to overwrite shared '/usr/share/doc/libegl1/changelog.Debian.gz', which
is different from other instances of package libegl1:i386
Preparing to unpack .../2-libglx0_1.7.0-2101~22.04_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libglx0:i386 (1.7.0-2101~22.04) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-WFP5wd/2-libglx0_1.7.0-2101
~22.04_i386.deb (--unpack):
trying to overwrite shared '/usr/share/doc/libglx0/changelog.Debian.gz', which
is different from other instances of package libglx0:i386
Preparing to unpack .../3-libgl1_1.7.0-2101~22.04_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libgl1:i386 (1.7.0-2101~22.04) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-WFP5wd/3-libgl1_1.7.0-2101~
22.04_i386.deb (--unpack):
trying to overwrite shared '/usr/share/doc/libgl1/changelog.Debian.gz', which i
s different from other instances of package libgl1:i386
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
Preparing to unpac
k .../4-libopengl0_1.7.0-2101~22.04_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libopengl0:i386 (1.7.0-2101~22.04) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-WFP5wd/4-libopengl0_1.7.0-2
101~22.04_i386.deb (--unpack):
trying to overwrite shared '/usr/share/doc/libopengl0/changelog.Debian.gz', whi
ch is different from other instances of package libopengl0:i386
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
Preparing to unpac
k .../5-libgles2_1.7.0-2101~22.04_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libgles2:i386 (1.7.0-2101~22.04) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-WFP5wd/5-libgles2_1.7.0-210
1~22.04_i386.deb (--unpack):
trying to overwrite shared '/usr/share/doc/libgles2/changelog.Debian.gz', which
is different from other instances of package libgles2:i386
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
Preparing to unpac
k .../6-libvdpau1_1.5-2105~22.04_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libvdpau1:i386 (1.5-2105~22.04) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-WFP5wd/6-libvdpau1_1.5-2105
~22.04_i386.deb (--unpack):
trying to overwrite shared '/usr/share/doc/libvdpau1/changelog.Debian.gz', whic
h is different from other instances of package libvdpau1:i386
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
Errors were encoun
tered while processing:
/tmp/apt-dpkg-install-WFP5wd/0-libglvnd0_1.7.0-2101~22.04_i386.deb
/tmp/apt-dpkg-install-WFP5wd/1-libegl1_1.7.0-2101~22.04_i386.deb
/tmp/apt-dpkg-install-WFP5wd/2-libglx0_1.7.0-2101~22.04_i386.deb
/tmp/apt-dpkg-install-WFP5wd/3-libgl1_1.7.0-2101~22.04_i386.deb
/tmp/apt-dpkg-install-WFP5wd/4-libopengl0_1.7.0-2101~22.04_i386.deb
/tmp/apt-dpkg-install-WFP5wd/5-libgles2_1.7.0-2101~22.04_i386.deb
